# How to find the mode and median of a Gamma distribution?

Tags: statistics, gamma-distribution

A random variable has Gamma distribution with mean of $10$ and standard deviation of $5$. The mode and median are to be found.

I realize that this means that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both $\sqrt{5}$. My professor told me that R is needed for one of them, and the exact answer can be found another way. Please help. I am confused at what to do.

Comment: I tried to make the text look good. I consulted MathJax. It still doesn't look right. Sorry. Make the directions clearer.

Comment: standard distribution=standard deviation? And what is $R$?

Comment: My mistake. Standard deviation. R is a program to do quick calculations, plots, etc.

Comment: Than it should be written as R, not as a variable $R$

Comment: I didn't make that edit.

Comment: Did you look for the PDF of this gamma distribution?

Comment: Please. Tell us WHICH of the parametrizations of the Gamma distributions you're using.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT to use the parameters as specified by OP:

From the [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) wiki page we have that mean is $\alpha\beta$, standard deviation is $\beta\sqrt\alpha$ and the mode is $(\alpha-1)\beta$

So divide $\alpha\beta=10$ by $\beta\sqrt\alpha=5$ to get $\sqrt\alpha=2$, so $\alpha=4$ and $\beta=\frac{5}{2}$

The mode is $(\alpha-1)\beta=\frac{15}{2}$

The median cannot be calculated in a simple closed form, so you have to use some numeric method or software which can calculate the inverse of the lower incomplete gamma function $\gamma$.

$$F(x;\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\gamma(\alpha,x/\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

From where:

$$x=\beta\gamma^{-1}\left(\alpha,\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{2}\right)$$

OLD POST:

From the [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) wiki page we have that mean is $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, standard deviation is $\frac{\sqrt\alpha}{\beta}$ and the mode is $\frac{\alpha-1}{\beta}$

So divide $\frac{\alpha}{\beta}=10$ by $\frac{\sqrt\alpha}{\beta}=5$ to get $\sqrt\alpha=2$, so $\alpha=4$ and $\beta=\frac{2}{5}$

The mode is $\frac{\alpha-1}{\beta}=\frac{15}{2}$

The median cannot be calculated in a simple closed form, so you have to use some numeric method or software which can calculate the inverse of the lower incomplete gamma function $\gamma$.

$$F(x;\alpha,\beta)=\frac{\gamma(\alpha,\beta x)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}=\frac{1}{2}$$

From where:

$$x=\frac{1}{\beta}\gamma^{-1}\left(\alpha,\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{2}\right)$$

Comment: In class it was stated that mean is equal to $\alpha$ x $\beta$

Comment: Do you use in the textbook/class the shape-scale or shape-rate parametrization? I mean what is $\alpha$ and what is $\beta$ and what is formula for your Gamma pdf?

Comment: Shape-scale. $\alpha$ is shape and $\beta$ is scale.

Comment: If you use a non-standard notation, you should specify what it is and save my time

Comment: I couldn't tell you what is standard or non-standard in statistics.

Comment: I edited my post for your notation. Please double check whether everything is correct.

Comment: Thanks, but why do you divide the mean by the standard deviation anyway? Just to solve for $\alpha$? Why not divide the standard deviation by the mean, or calculate $\alpha$ in some other way?

Comment: You may solve for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in whichever way you want.